# Programmatically generate color chart?

Tags: c#

In C#, how could I generate the following image programmatically?

http://deathmatchgame.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/color_picker.png

I am well-aware of how long this would take to process. That's fine. Performance is not top priority at the moment.

**Edit** Note that I am not interested in the right region of the image that only shows a gray-scale gradient.

Comment: Graphics.DrawImage() is quite fast.  You don't have to generate this image at runtime, you only need to know the inverse mapping of position to color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the looks of it, that's an HSL color chart.  The below code would generate a 2d array of colors that should correspond to what's in the image.  I've left the implementation of `FromHSL` up to you, as well as how to get from this array to an actual image:

```
const int size = 1000;
const double ratio = 1.0 / size;
const double saturation = 1.0;
Color[,] colors = new Color[size,size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    double lightness = 1.0 - i*ratio;
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        double hue = j*ratio;
        colors[i, j] = FromHSL(hue, saturation, lightness);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This image is a HSL (not HSV, white is S=0 in HSV) color space, with S at 100%, H on the horizontal axis, and L on the vertical axis. (The grayscale gradient is S=0) You could use the conversions at https://web.archive.org/web/20141023005253/http://bobpowell.net/RGBHSB.aspx and just iterate over all the pixels in your rectangle.

As a simple eyedropper palette, this gives you fully saturated colors (and grays, with the bit on the right).

The windows color picker, for comparison, puts S on the vertical axis (with L=50%) in the big square, resulting in gray at the bottom with a separate slider for L. This is less useful as an eyedropper palette. Another commonly seen color picker form is a circle with hue around the circle and saturation as radius (generally this puts white at the center, by using HSV with V=100, and a separate slider for value)

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of sample projects out there to do something like that:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/colorwheelv1.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164113.aspx
- http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid6227A6F88369176FF1A3CDF19B33844D254DB5CC.aspx